# Grammatically and meaning of "He has started feeling the heat of the chill"

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context

> He has started feeling the heat of the chill.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct and does it make some sense?
We know that the word "heat" can be used in the following ways - "... in the heat of the moment" or "... feeling the heat".

So in the above sentence, is the writer trying to emphasize the cold weather?

Comment: I think it is a poor choice. I certainly understand the intent of the sentence: cold can burn (and cook), but "heat" is more a reference to temperature.

Answer (score 6):

It is grammatically sound but apparently doesn't make good sense, because of the opposition of *heat* and *chill*.

Informally, *[heat](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heat)* could refer to "intensity" and "undesirable amount of attention" and *[chill](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chill)* to "an uncomfortable and numbing sense of fear, dread, anxiety, or alarm" which might make sense, but in your "emphasize the cold weather" sense, *heat* doesn't work.

Comment: Unless the writer wanted to contrast the two words for reasons of style.

Answer (score 3):

I won't say it's wrong.  After all, Shakespeare wrote something similar:

> O heavy lightness! Serious vanity!
>
> Mis-shapen chaos of well-seeming forms!
>
> Feather of lead, bright smoke, cold fire, sick health!
>
> *Romeo and Juliet*

but if you're good enough to write like Shakespeare you really don't need our help!

Comment: Those contrasts were intentional. We don't know if the OP's "heat of the chill" intentionally sets up a contrast, or is just a result of poor judgment from using "feeling the heat of _" for a chill.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this can, in some ways, be a play on words.  When I read it, it does sound a little clunky.  On the other hand, John Lennon's book, "In His Own Write," is kind of similar.

Hope this helps (or knot).